# Synonymize [serverless] -> [serverless-framework]

Tags: support, synonym-request

Even though what [serverless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/serverless) tag wiki describes is essentially [cloud-computing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cloud-computing), questions invariably use it to denote [a specific software framework](https://github.com/serverless/serverless).

Comment: There are a lot of cloud-computing questions in [tag:serverless] that are not related to [tag:serverless-framework]. We need a cleanup before we can synonymize imo.

Comment: Serverless is a generic term for a form of cloud-computing, while serverless-framework seems to be a specific solution to develop serverless applications. They are not and should not be synonyms, that would amount to a specific library having a monopoly on the term.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I don't know... the general term may be off topic since SO is about using specific technologies and/or interchangeable with cloud computing. The ppl asking questions seem to be using it as a shorthand for the library, too. Perhaps you could elaborate in an answer?

Comment: Maybe, but that would sooner ask for blacklisting the tag, then making it a synonym for a specific library for building serverless applications.